# Serre condition and Unmixedness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local domain and $I$ be a height one ideal. Suppose the ideal $I$ satisfies the Serre condition $(S_2)$, then does it imply that $I$ is unmixed?

$I$ satisfies $(S_2)$ if ${\rm depth~} I_P\geq \min\{2,\dim I_P\}$. That is, at all height one primes of $R$, the depth of $I_P$ is at least 1 and at primes of height 2 and above, the depth of $I_P$ is at least 2 (as long as $P$ contains $I$). Now using the depth lemma it shows that at height 1 primes, the depth of $R_P/I_P$ is at least 0 and at height 2 primes and above, the depth of $R_P/I_P$ is at least 1. Doesnt this show that $R/I$ is unmixed? Is there any mistake in the argument? Thanks in advance.